# Прошу помощи с listView с# UWP

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

```
App.structure.Add(new School()
    {
        id = Id,
        Number = number,
        Type = type,
       Info = info,
       Sour = sour                                   
    });

    jsonArray_Item = jsonArray_Item.Next;
}

SchoolList.Items.Clear();
load.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

SchoolList.ItemsSource = App.structure;
```

Тут я заполняю `list`, а потом вывожу по этому листу `ListView`. "Sour" – это ссылка на изображение (в которой меняется только последние цифры). Проблема в том, что не по всем ссылкам имеется изображение, как в случае отсутствия изображения с сервера, выводить альтернативное?

На счет конвертора, у меня поле то не пустое...

```
string sour = "http://www.schoolapp.ru/img_schools/" + number + ".jpg";
```

Надо проверять, есть ли изображение по ссылке... Либо как–то видоизменить код.

Comment: Поищите по сайту, было уже. С MultiBinding'ом, например.

Comment: А нельзя ли, сделать `Sour` свойством и в гетере выполнять проверку?

Answer (score 1):

Можно конвертер сделать, который будет проверять, если поле url пустое, то отдавать какой-то захардкоданный url.

например если вы используете привязку:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl, Converter={StaticResource CheckForNullConverter}}"/>
```

здесь конвертер должен быть указан в ресурсах

```
xmlns:converters="using:App.Converters"

<converters:CheckForNullConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
```

и он должен быть реализован

```
public class CheckForNullConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, ...)
{
 return value==null?"defaultImagePath":value;
}
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?